# Basis of subspace in a lesser dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

I have four linear independent vectors from R^5 that span a subspace. When putting them together to form an orthonormal basis for the subspace I'm left with a choice. Which of the two bases below are preferable? And what are the consequences of them?

```
1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1

vs

1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is preferable, because you can see that it creates a 4-dimensional subspace. As well, you are also able to see that the last row in the second, creates a one-dimensional null-space.